# Sql query (selfjoin)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am new in this forum and I would know if it's possible to get a quickly help about to make a SQL query related to an Oracle environment.

I have this following query for example :

```
SELECT table3.numero 
FROM table1 table1
    INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.tbl1_id 
    INNER JOIN table3 ON table3.id = table2.tbl2_id;
```

I would like to add a new condition to display the same field in the select (table3.numero) based on the value of a field called options existing in the table1.

The options field contains mixed values (null and table1.id). There is a link between these values. Table1.id in the options field represents the table1.id of records having a value null. We can consider that records having a null value are the parents of records having a value different than null.

So, my question is to know if it's possible to add in the select another table3.numero which will represent value for parents records and another one for children records.

I don't know exactly how to do this query.

Thanks for help.

Test data for table1

```
id      options
------  -------
151515  151516
151516
151517
151518  151517
```

table3

```
numero 
------ 
4333
2452
4245
1121
```

table3.numero (parents = table1.option is null)

```
8844
5515
1518
1444
```

table3.numero (children => table1.option)

```
8789
5454
3654
2114
```

Comment: add some sample data, your requirement is not clear.

Comment: The short answer is that it's most likely possible, but you need to be more precise. Show example of data and example of desired output

Comment: Like this query for example :
SELECT table3.numero, table3.numero (parent), table3.numero (children)
FROM table1 table1
INNER JOIN table1 table12 ON table12.id = table1.id and table1.options is null (parents) and  table1.options = table1.id (contains id of parents records)

Comment: I don't know if i need to add a subquery at the from level or at the select level?

Comment: I am sorry because I don't have a sample data.

Comment: You have to create sample data based on whatever you are explaining, WIthout it, your explanation is not clear.

Comment: Even if you don't have data, if you know the logic you need, you can build a small set of data to better explain the logic you want to implement. This would be really helpful for people to build some test case, write some code and help you

Comment: Of course you're new here, but please **edit your question** to include additional information. Answers are for post answers and comments are for posting comments.

Comment: Your test data is confused. Where is table2 data. With IDs what is relationship between tables. If you want us to help you need to explain your problem clearly.

Comment: i need table 2 just to make a jointure

Comment: I don't know exactly how to explain my problem. I have 3 joins between 3 tables. I would like to display a column from a table 3 like the example I posted before. Moreover, i would like to display the same column twice from the table 3 but based on a condition.

Comment: The condition is based on a column of the table 1. For example I would like to display the column table3.numero where the column of the table 1 is null and where the same column of the table 1 is equal to the id of the record having the column of the table 1 null.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you mean. I created samples of what it sounds like you have.

**Table1**

```
id      options
151515  151516
151516  
151517  
151518  151517
```

**Table3**

```
id      numero
151515  8789
151516  8844
151517  5515
151518  5454
```

**Results**

```
id      numero  parent  child
151515  8789    8844    8789
151518  5454    5515    5454
```

**Query used**

```
SELECT T3.ID,T3.NUMERO,T3_PARENT.NUMERO PARENT,T3.NUMERO CHILD
FROM TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON T1.ID=T3.ID AND T1.OPTIONS IS NOT NULL
JOIN TABLE3 T3_PARENT ON T3_PARENT.ID=T1.OPTIONS
```

Comment: Thank you very much hewills. I think that's what I want to do. I am going to try it tomorrow morning and I'll keep you in touch if it gives me the result that I expect.